# What does "java -classpath .:" mean?

Tags: java, classpath

There is no mention of this [in the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), but I get a ClassNotFoundException when calling it without the `:`.

Full line:

```
java -classpath .:soy-20100708.jar HelloWorld
```

This works too though...

```
java -classpath :soy-20100708.jar HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:` is used to separate classpath entries.

Therefore `.:soy-20100708.jar` means "search in the current directory and inside `soy-20100708.jar`".

The second variant ":soy-20100708.jar" has no special meaning (it is malformed). It *might* be interpreted somehow, but I'm not aware of any special meaning.

Can you post the content of the `jar` file? Which files does it contain and in which directories?

Comment: @Jaochim: It's from the Closure templates tutorial, here is the link to the zip with all .jars: http://closure-templates.googlecode.com/files/closure-templates-for-java-latest.zip .

Comment: @Blub: `;` is used on Windows, because `:` is already used inside paths there (for indicating a drive). Unix-like platforms use `:`.

Comment: Also: there's no `HelloWorld.class` in `soy-20100708.jar`, so it must be in the current directory, which means you need to include `.` in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The "." means the current directory is searched too, the ":" is your path separator. As described on [this website](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/classpath.html), the separator is platform-dependent:

> The CLASSPATH separator character is platform dependent. You can
>   discover it with the system properties as well. It will usually be ;
>   or :. You must put ., the current directory, explicitly on the
>   CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

The colon ":" is path separator in unix environment, while on windows the semicolon ";" separates the path.  i.e. you can write:

```
java -classpath a.jar:b.jar OR java -classpath a.jar;b.jar
```

And it loads two jars to path.
While period "." period stands for current directory. Beware that directories are search only for *.class files not packages.

the version starting with ":" is not covered by documentation (as far as i know) so it just probably works by accident (pobably adding current dir to classpath aswel)

EDIT:
I just found out, that dir/* finds all jars in dir in JAVA 6

Comment: `:` is the standard path separator on Unix systems, just as `;` is on Windows systems. Use the one relevant to the system you are on.